# Is a Polar Decomposition of Normal Operators Unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Here I am concerned with finite dimensional complex inner product spaces.

We know that the (semi)positive operator in such a decomposition is always unique, and so it's clear that the polar decomposition of every invertible operator is unique. But is it necessarily unique for normal operators in general? (We may as well exclude isometries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polar decomposition will fail to be unique whenever $A$ is non-invertible, whether or not $A$ is normal.  You may find it interesting, however, that the two matrices in the polar decomposition commute if and only if $A$ is normal.

For a concrete example: take 
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0\\&&\ddots\\&&&0}
$$
Note that $UA = AU = A$ whenever $U$ is unitary and has $(1,0,\dots,0)$ as its first column.